# eb ssh suddenly asking for a password

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I can't remember the last time I was prompted for the password. I am also curious to know the reason for it.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen it that way, but it looks like your ssh-key is created with a passphrase. You need to enter that to use the key.